# Custom Dialog with game score android

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I've got a huge problem. When I had AlertBox everything was OK, but I would change it to custom dialog box with pretty good graphic.
With AlertBox it was displaying the current scores and highscore.

When I changed it to Custom Dialog box it's showing nothing.

**CustomDialogClass.java**

```
public class CustomDialogClass extends Dialog
{
    public CustomDialogClass(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


        /** It will hide the title */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);

    }
}
```

**GameActivity.java** (fragments with custom dialog box)

```
@Override
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    surfaceCreated = false;
    stopDrawingThread();
  }




  public void customizeDialog() {
    int highest = PrefUtil.getHighestScore(this);
    String text = null;
    if (currentPoint > highest) {
      highest = currentPoint;
      PrefUtil.setHighestScore(this, currentPoint);
    } else {
    }

    text = "Current Points: " + currentPoint + "\nThe Best Score: " + highest;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Game Over");
    builder.setMessage(text);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        playSwooshing();
        restart();
      }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Exit Game", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,Bye.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            playSwooshing();
            finish();
        }

    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog = builder.show();
  }
```

and the other fragment:

```
private void onGameOver() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {
        if (!isFinishing()) {
          soundPool.play(soundIds[SOUND_DIE], 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 1);
          CustomDialogClass customizeDialog = new CustomDialogClass(GameActivity.this);
          customizeDialog.show();        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Where is a problem? Can someone fix it?
Now it's showing only my layout file, without any data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not displaying your data because you're not setting your data. In your middle code fragment where you're creating your dialog using a `Builder` you're not using your custom dialog, so apparently that code is no longer being called. Likewise in your last fragment where you do create a custom dialog, you're not setting any the data.

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout):

> If you want a custom layout in a dialog, create a layout and add it to an `AlertDialog` by calling `setView()` on your `AlertDialog.Builder` object.
>
> By default, the custom layout fills the dialog window, but you can still use `AlertDialog.Builder` methods to add buttons and a title.

Comment: I'm newbie, could You edit it for me please? Greetings

Comment: No. This isn't a place to find someone to do your work for you. Read through the example in the documentation I linked and try to apply it to your situation.